# Spark How to create a DataFrame from a list of file in another DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Apache Spark, if I have a `DataFrame` that is a list of CSV files, how can I create a `DataFrame` from the content of all the files listed in the first `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think the number of files should be small. You can just collect the file paths to the driver and use them to create DataFrame. E.g.,

```
  val filePathDF = sc.parallelize(Seq("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt")).toDF("path")
  val df = sqlContext.read.text(filePathDF.collect().map(_.getString(0)): _*)
  df.show()
```

`text` is a 1.6 API. If you are using a pre 1.6 Spark, you can use `format("text").load(...)` instead.

Comment: The list could be large, in the millions of files. Would this solution work?

Comment: I don't think it will work for millions of files since it will crash millions of `DataFrame`s. Which file system are you using? Processing millions of files in a file system is usually pretty slow.